# What is the VBA equivalent of IF x == y or x == z then

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

In Python, I would write:

```
if x == y or x == z: 
    #do something
```

How can I write this in VBA (for Excel)?

Here is what I'm actually doing:

```
lang = Left(objFile.Name, 4)
        
For Each LangCode In Split("1030,1053,1044,1035", ",")
    #do something
```

But this incorrectly returns '1033333' as True so Id like to be more explicit.

Comment: `iserror(application.match(lang, split("1030,1053,1044",","),0))` will be True if `lang` isn't in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
if x=y or x=z then
    'do stuff
end if
```

And on your for statement

```
For Each LangCode In Split("1030,1053,1044,1035", ",")
   #do something
next langcode
```

The end of loops, if statements if not on the same line require an ending statement.